# Why do I get the error <!–html_preserve–> when I try embed a plot_ly graph in R Presentation?

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly

Basically, I'm trying to make an R presentation file. Everything was going fine until I tried to add a plot_ly graph. When I hit Preview, everything works except on the slide where the graph is supposed to be, it has  on the top and  on the bottom of the slide. Why would it do this and how can I fix it?

```
plot_ly(data = allstocks, x = Date, y = PortReturns, mode = "line")
```

Above is my code for the slide. Oh, btw, when I run the code, it works fine. But just not in the slide show.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.